# fb:login-button image change

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please refer the following location. At the top of the website, I have  sign in facebook  button, when using the facebook javascript.

http://www.innovationadvice.com/

Is it possible to change the button type the following url:

http://dribbble.com/shots/231479-Sign-in-with-Facebook-or-Twitter.

Give any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I assume, since you've tagged this question as jquery, you want a javascript solution.

With Facebook JavaScript (and other) SDK's you can make a "login link" and assign it to whatever you want. Check out FB.login: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Here's an example I've used where I put it in another function:

```
function loginUser() {    
    FB.login(
        function(response) {
            getStatus(); //This is a call to a different function...
        }, 
    {scope:'user_likes, offline_access'}
    );     
}
```

And then on your image:

```
<a href="#" onClick="loginUser(); return false;"><img src="ur_image.png" /></a>
```

Comment: I have used above coding. Plase refer the following location.

Comment: @user1101236 looks like they are using the Login Plugin. You'd change that with css, but its a hack. Use my JS to do it the right way. What is your remaining question?

Answer (score 1):

just see the css style used by those button using chrome and apply the same style to your buttons.